# Is my time complexity decorator concise and does what it does?

Tags: python, data-structures

I wrote a decorator to time if certain operations or function is really linear, quadratic etc when `n` increases.

```py
DataTypes = Union[List[int], Dict[int, int], None]
#  callable that takes any number of arguments and returns any value.

# pylint: disable=invalid-name
def data_factory(data_type: str, n: int) -> DataTypes:
    if data_type == "array":
        return list(range(n))
    if data_type == "dict":
        return {i: i for i in range(n)}
    if data_type is None:
        return None
    raise ValueError(f"Invalid data_type: {data_type}")


def time_complexity(
    data_type: str, repeat: int = 1, plot: bool = False
) -> Callable[[Callable[..., Any]], Callable[..., Tuple]]:
    def decorator(func: Callable[..., Any]) -> Callable[..., Tuple]:
        def wrapper(n_sizes: List[int], *args: Any, **kwargs: Dict[str, Any]) -> Tuple:
            avg_times = []
            median_times = []
            best_times = []
            worst_times = []

            for n in n_sizes:
                # create a list of n elements
                data_structure = data_factory(data_type, n)
                # note array is created outside the loop
                runtimes = []
                for _ in range(repeat):
                    start_time = time.perf_counter()

                    # pylint: disable=expression-not-assigned,line-too-long
                    func(n, data_structure, *args, **kwargs) if data_type else func(
                        n, *args, **kwargs
                    )  # <--- this is where it calls the function with n or data_structure as argument
                    end_time = time.perf_counter()
                    runtimes.append(end_time - start_time)

                avg_times.append(np.mean(runtimes))
                median_times.append(np.median(runtimes))
                best_times.append(np.min(runtimes))
                worst_times.append(np.max(runtimes))

            if plot:
                plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
                plt.plot(n_sizes, avg_times, "o-", label="Average")
                plt.plot(n_sizes, median_times, "o-", label="Median")
                plt.plot(n_sizes, best_times, "o-", label="Best")
                plt.plot(n_sizes, worst_times, "o-", label="Worst")
                plt.xlabel("Size of Input (n)")
                plt.ylabel("Execution Time (s)")
                plt.legend()
                plt.grid(True)
                plt.title(f"Time Complexity of {func.__name__}")
                plt.show()

            return n_sizes, avg_times, median_times, best_times, worst_times

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Using it will be like the following:

```py
@time_complexity(data_type="array", repeat=10, plot=True)
def list_append(n: int, array) -> None:
    array.append(n)


@time_complexity(data_type="array", repeat=10, plot=True)
def list_insert(n: int, array) -> None:
    array.insert(0, n)

# list_append(range(1000000, 10000001, 1000000))
# list_insert(range(1000000, 10000001, 1000000))
```

I wonder if this implementation is good enough to have a visual idea, excluding external uncontrollable factors such as CPU etc.

Comment: *"does what it does"* is a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)). *"is...concise"*: that is a matter of opinion and thus off topic. *"good enough"*: that is a matter of opinion thus off topic. Also, those are 3 questions, and thus the question is too broad.

Comment: This sounds like a question more suitable for code-review.SE.